# fs.readFileSync() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io

I tried all this steps to integrate bpmn properties panel in localhost like [Integration of Properties panel in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062625/bpmn-io-examples-not-working-in-localhost).

After this I got `Uncaught Error: fs.readFileSync is not a function`.
How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you provide the code section which is throwing the error?

Comment: Questions about code need to show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

do `var fs=require('fs')` to to use file system module

Comment: Is it working by mistake I installed very old version.

Comment: how did you resolve this? I am also having issue with fs module with bpmn

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try again,the maintainer of npm accidentally unpublished the 'fs' package (for a short period of time, but still, what a bummer).
http://status.npmjs.org/incidents/dw8cr1lwxkcr