# How to browserify node `fs.readFileSync` to make it work in Chrome/Safari/IE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browserify

I have a `node` module that uses modules that depend on `fs` like making use of `fs.readFileSync` etc. I cannot manually remove those dependencies since are at 2nd or 3rd level of the package dependencies having level 0 my root module.

Given that,
I have to run those modules in the browser, so I have tried both `browserify` and `webpack`.
My `webpack` configuration is the following

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: './pgapi',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    noParse: /node_modules\/json-schema\/lib\/validate\.js/,
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
      , {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: "transform?brfs"
        }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js']
  },
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
        //new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        //new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __DEV__: true
        })
    ]
};
```

and I'm using `browserify` as alternative with the `brfs` transform to try to take care of the `fs.readFileSync` etc.

After building the `bundle.js` I run `babel` since when in `Safari` there is no complete compliance to ES5 `strict mode` and also it take cares of the `arrow operator` and of `let` and `const` that are not supported as well using this script:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
var code=fs.readFileSync(args[0])
var res=require("babel-core").transform(code, {
  plugins: [
     "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
     "transform-es2015-constants",
     "transform-es2015-block-scoping"]
});
console.log(res.code)
```

So I do like
`$ webpack` or `$ browserify mymodule.js -o dist/bundle.js -t brfs`

and then on `dist/bundle.js`

`$ node babelify.js dist/bundle.js > out.js`.

What happens then is a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fs` (see [here](https://github.com/substack/brfs/issues/71))
that seems to be due to the fact that the `brsf` transform does works on static expression eval so that it does not understand variables in `fs.readFileSync(varname)`.
I'm using [MacGap](https://github.com/MacGapProject/MacGap1) in Xcode test the `WebView` client code on `El Capitan`.

How to get rid of this at build time?

Comment: How would you get files in a browser that has no access to the filesystem anyway ?

Comment: I do not need that, it's required by dependencies, some of which I'm not using at all, but I cannot remove them. In other cases it's like local `json`files that the `brsf` transform will load at build time - see the link about that. The problem seems to be that the static evaluation of `brfs` does not take in account all cases of most of modules that makes use of variables when calling `fs.readFileSync(fileName)`, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640177/browserify-with-requirefs

Comment: @adeneo yes I know that one but there you can do `var src = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/file.txt');`, here I cannot modify submodules, since I get them from the official repo, and just build them.

Comment: I have no idea? Again, the browser can't access files, so "browserifying" the `fs` module really makes no sense to me, and your depencies won't be able to get the files they are trying to get anyway?

Comment: Yes formally that is true, but you know it's a syntax error at compile time, no code in my module would call any submodules that are requiring `fs`, it's a dependency of some sub-modules, like module `mime`  - mime types modules, makes use of `fs.readFileSync` somewhere, but I would never do that call at run time. And `protobuf` module as well, etc.

Comment: Then, you need to clean up the code you're including so it doesn't use things that won't work client-side.  It sounds like you're trying to include a giant fur ball of code, some of which could only work on the server rather than carefully sorting out what really belongs on the client.

Comment: What happens with npm is that if you build a module A that depends on B and C, and C depends on D and E, while B depends on D, your module will end up depending on B,C,D,E at some version. Since you cannot modify level 1 dependencies B and C, you must include D and E, that's a big issue with npm I think, that was addressed putting all modules at root level in the `node_modules` folder to dedup submodules, but there are too much depth of dependencies at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue.

Identify which module is calling `mime` and find an alternative module. For me, this was `url-loader` which depends on `mime`.

I replaced it with `file-loader` which doesn't depend on `mime`, and hence not the `fs`. Ensure to uninstall `url-loader` as it will still throw the error!