# TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function in electron without webpack or Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to read a file in electron without webpack or Browserify like this,

```
const fs = require('fs');
let content = fs.readFileSync('./random.json' , {encoding: "utf8"})
console.log(content)
```

but I keep getting this

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43103587 etc. are you trying to require this on the electron or web side of things?

Comment: @DaveNewton the web part

Comment: I think there are several possibilities. 1. They way you launches the electron app. 2. Used browserify some where. I'd like to see a stand along demo for more detail.