# TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function nodeJs (Browserify)

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am having an error with Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function when i use browserify.

I tried using window.require as suggested in this post but now i am receiving Uncaught TypeError: window.require is not a function. instead

May I know if there is any suggestion to workaround this issue. I am using browserify with nodejs.

Comment: Have you read this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640177/browserify-with-requirefs

Comment: Could you shares a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your nodejs version & operative system?