# Express-browserify and Watson Visual Recognition - TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: express, browserify, ibm-watson, fs

I'm trying to get the Watson Visual Recognition to run client side by using express-browserify with reference to the [node-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples/browserify) for watson-developer-cloud. The `VisualRecognitionV3` makes use of the `fs` package hence I get the `fs.existsSync` error when I'm trying to call it from the client-side as the browser doesn't know which filesystem to use. My question is how do I go about creating a so called 'abstraction layer' as I am restricted to using the `express-browserify` package for cross origin calls.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640177/browserify-with-requirefs) is pretty helpful in shedding some light but I'm not sure where to start regarding the 'abstraction layer' or if there are any other solutions. Also, would something like socket.io work for this? I've linked a clone of the directory [here](https://github.com/kaishinaw/traffic-image-classifier) as it seems less clunky than pasting the multiple portions below.

The repository can be cloned and just requires a personal iam_apikey with relevant launch configuration. Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to sort this out with express-browserify due to the `require(fs)` from browser issue but I was able to get it running using the express-ws package